# CSS word-break property not working on SVG text

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I have the following SVG element were i have a text on the graph.

```
   wrapper.append("text")
          .text(data[i].name)
          .attr("x", 10)
          .attr("y", 30)
          .attr("class", "text-class")
```

I want to apply
***word-break: break-word;*** to the text so that it falls to the second line when the characters are more and doesn't overflow the chart. i tried styling the class ***text-class*** also tried inline styling like `.attr("word-break", 'break-word')`. but it doesn't seems to be working. can someone tell me how can i achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

inline styling usually looks like

```
.attr('style', 'word-break: break-word;')
```